# Change distance between page number and bottom edge of page

Tags: positioning, margins, page-numbering

I am trying to make my page numbers `.75in` from the bottom of the page. 
Currently they are about `.5in` or so.

I think `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` will work but what is the option to change this without changing anything else in the document?

Comment: The distances in LaTeX are measured from the top and the left of the page. One has to know the other details of your setup to help you.

Answer (score 11):

`\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}` should do the job.

Comment: The OP specified that he/she didn't want to change anything else in the document.

Answer (score 8):

Add the following code by the end of your document header (**just before** `\begin{document}`). The `calc` package allows arithmetics with lengths and the `\setlength` just modifies `\footskip` to the desired value:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\footskip}{\paperheight
  -(1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight)
  -0.75in}
```

For more details on paper layouts see e.g. [*The Not So Short
Introduction to LATEX2e*](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort), section *Page Layout*.